# CRM 2011 outlook client: Do NOT autosynchronise when offline?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

When i'm in offline modus with Dynamics CRM 2011 for outlook installed, i get a message that asks to connect with the online database. Can i disable outlook to try to connect automaticly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the simple setting to do this in outlook. Go to file - CRM. In the syncronisation tab you can uncheck the checkbox.